# Operate on multiple rows of dataframe simultaneously in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, rows

I'm sure someone has asked this (very basic) question before, but I must be searching for the wrong thing because I can't find an answer:

I frequently need to perform operations that involve combining data from multiple rows of the same dataframe. I know how to do this with a looping construct, e.g.

```
for (i in 2:nrow(df)) { df$result[i] <- df$data[i] - df$data[i-1] }
for (i in 12:nrow(df)) { j <- i - 11; df$result[i] <- prod(df$data[j:i]) }
```

Is there a general solution for these types of operations that does not involve looping? Or is looping actually the best way to do it in R?

Comment: Thank you! Both of those solutions get me the first case, where I need to work on "this row" and "one previous row." Is there a similar solution for the second case, where I need to work on "this row" and "eleven previous rows"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try subsetting your data frame, e.g. this:

```
for (i in 2:nrow[df]) { df$result[i] <- df$data[i] - df$data[i-1] }
```

becomes:

```
df$result[2:nrow(df)] <- df$data[2:nrow(df)] - df$data[1:nrow(df)-1]
```

Note: `nrow()` is a function AFAIK, so you should call it using parentheses, not square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

In base R:

```
df$result[2:nrow(df)] = diff(df$data)
df$result2[13:nrow(df)] = diff(df$data,12)
```

Or `dplyr`:

```
df$result = dplyr::lag(df$data)
df$result2 = dplyr::lag(df$data, 12)
```